# Получение переменной из сообщения

Tags: python, telethon

Суть вопроса: Как установить вместо "**( '123')**" - текст, который будет указан в смс? (Есть проверка на само смс. Тоесть - !spam. Нужно, чтобы после !spam указывалась переменная str с текстом *(await event.respond( '123'))*, и после этого переменная int *(x = int(input("Введите кол-во сообщений: ")))*

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

with TelegramClient('name', api_id="123", api_hash="abc") as client:

   @client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='!'))
   async def handler(event):
      i = 0
      if event.text=="!spam":
         x = int(input("Введите кол-во сообщений: "))
         while i < x:
            await event.respond( '123')
            print ('Message send!')
            i += 1

   client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# ...
text = event.text.split()
if text[0] == "!spam":
         x = int(text[2])
         while i < x:
            await event.respond( text[1] )
            print ('Message send!')
            i += 1
# ...
```